# Find a generating function for which $A(n)={n \choose 2}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In the book I'm using, $A(x)$ denotes the formal power series (generating function), $A(x) = \sum a_ix^i$.
I'm really stuck on this problem. Thanks for any help.

My attempt after the given hint:
$$\begin{align}
A(x)&=\sum_{n\geq 0} \binom{n}{2}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^2}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^{n})\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{n\geq 0} x^{n}\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{1}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2} \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}
\end{align}$$
Sorry, I'm new to $\rm \LaTeX$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean $a_n=\binom{n}{2}$ and $A(x) =\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n= \sum_{n\geq 0} \binom{n}{2}x^n$?

Then note that 
$$\binom{n}{2}x^n=\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot n(n-1) x^{n-2}=\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^{n})$$
and recall the basic generating function $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

What is $A(x)$?

Comment: What is $D^2$ here?

Comment: And I believe the question is saying when n is substituted as x, the whole sum turn out to be $n \choose 2$

Comment: $D^2$ is the second derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: I don't think so. Otherwise the g.f. is simply $x/2+x^2/2$.

Comment: Where this question come from? A book? Any web-link?

Comment: It's question made up by our professor.

Comment: Following your hint, I got $x^2/(1-x)^3$, is that right?

Comment: Actually it is the shifted one $x/(1-x)^3=x+3x^2+6x^3+10x^4+15x^5+\dots$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89469/discussion-between-davidh-and-robert-z).

Comment: $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\ne\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for $n\ne 0$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I realized that without my coffee, i forget even the definition of binomial coefficient... Sorry for the mess!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\binom{n}{2}x^n=\frac12 x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^n$, $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}{2}x^n=\frac12 x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}.$$We can double-check by the binomial theorem: the $x^n$ coefficient is $$\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-2)!}\prod_{j=1}^{n-2}(-2-j)=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}=\binom{n}{2}.$$